# How to debug in Ms cobol 2.20

Tags: visual-studio, cobol

In MS COBOL 2.20, I want to know how I can debug my program to see line-by-line execution just like debugging in Visual Basic 6.0.

What are the steps in debugging my cobol program?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not aware of a free cobol debugger specifically for MS cobol.

Netcobol is a pretty good one built on Visual Studio but it's paid software.

If you're not writing code that is dependent on MS-only cobol features you can get opencobol from [www.opencobol.org](http://www.opencobol.org) for free, cut-and-paste your code and use [this program](http://sourceforge.net/projects/tp-cobol-debugg/) from sourceforge to debug it/

Comment: Hi thank you for the reply is that opencobol can run my program which is i coded from ms cobol?Thank you in advance.

Comment: COBOL is fairly portable between versions. Since you're doing what appears to be entry-level homework it's likely you'll be able to use it.

Answer (score 1):

Compile:

```
c:\>cobol yourprog/E;
```

This generates yourprog.dbo   and   yourprog.dbg

Debug:

```
c:\>viewcob yourprog
```

Viewcob.exe was part of the original product from Microsoft.